# Graph API: Posting as contributor to shared albums

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Shared albums is a quite new feature of Facebook.

I'm encountering an issue with the Graph API while trying to publish photos to a shared album. The issue is actually related to the ID of the album.

As user A, I create an album getting the ID 1 and I add user B as contributor.
As user B, I can retrieve the album 1 using the Graph API but the "can_upload" flag is set to "false". Which prevents contributor B to upload photos to this album.
When I try to get the album's information as user B using facebook.com, it looks like the album has a different ID than 1, let's call it 2. When I retrieve album information as user B using ID 2 with Graph API, the "can_upload" flag is correctly showing "true".

Apparently the original's album ID is known as a different ID to album contributors. But how can I find out the ID allowing contributors to upload photos to it?

Answer (score 0):

As there seems to be no API call to retrieve the ID (2) of the album to be used while publishing as contributor (user B), this is how one can manage to get it:

- As user B (contributor), get the info of the album using its original
  ID (1). Make sure to include field "cover_photo" in the request.
- Get the info of the cover photo, using its ID retrieved above. Make
  sure to include the field "link" in the request. Parse the "link"
  field in order to retrieve the value of the parameter "set" which
  contains the album ID.
- Get the album ID by extracting it from the value above. The format is
  something like "a.1234567890" or "a.1234567890.2345678901" where the
  contributor's album ID (2) would be 1234567890.